# Use Nancy whit Owin and WebForms

Tags: asp.net, owin, nancy

There is a method for `esclude` aspx page from pipeline in the use `nancy.Owin` in a old webform **site project not compiled**?

When I configure **nancy** the post-back and the request is an aspx page the post-back is deleted because **nancy** delete it and recall the page.

```
public void NancyConfig(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseNancy(options =>
    {
        options.Bootstrapper = new MyBootstrapper();
        options.PerformPassThrough = (context => context.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    });

    app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
}
```

The `options.PerformPassThrough` wipe the post-back content and call the page. For not post-back is ok but in post-back elaboration this present an infinite loop.

How to configure `NancyFx` for not wipe post-back in passtrought option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'have modified the nancy official 1.4 sources to esclude from .aspx and other page from pipeline, returning the request postback whitouth delete it.
You can try this modify [here](https://github.com/BaiShouDan/Nancy/commit/47cdb97d49fe1c9748d5b883de487bdca64324b9) .

- File modified: Nancy/src/Nancy/Owin/NancyMiddleware.cs
- Here te code to apply at line 82:

  ```
              //Check if the webform is not present inthe path ".aspx"
              //if present move to next
              if (owinRequestPath.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(".aspx")
              || owinRequestPath.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(".asmx")
              || owinRequestPath.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(".ascx")
              || owinRequestPath.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(".ashx")
              || owinRequestPath.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(".asmx")
              || owinRequestPath.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(".asax")
              ) return next.Invoke(environment);
  ```

Comment: I use this in a production system without any problem